# Calculating week numbers in PHP using Year, is it a bug?

Tags: php

That's strange, I don't know if it's a bug, but please, someone try it.

Do that on PHP

```
echo date("Y-W",strtotime("2014W05 -1 weeks"));
```

The result will be 2014-04, right? YEAR-WEEKNUMBER. No problem at all. 
But now, try this:

```
echo date("Y-W",strtotime("2014W02 -1 weeks"));
```

Why it's 2013-01, why 2013? What's wrong? It should be 2014-01, right?

What I'm doing wrong? Is it a bug?

My PHP version: 5.4.22

Comment: Would you edit the version of PHP you are using into the question? This may be a known bug with the version you're using.

Comment: This might be it: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63927

Comment: The manual for `strtotime` says: "Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2".

Comment: [php 5.5, 5.4.9, 5.4...](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hlw2qd)

Comment: http://3v4l.org/bfbP2 seems like it was introduced in PHP 5.1

Comment: How <i>didn't</i> your provide the PHP version you are using in this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Y is year from the date
o is ISO-8601 year number
```

So if you do it like

```
echo date("o-W",strtotime("2014W05 -1 weeks"))."<br/>";

echo date("o-W",strtotime("2014W02 -1 weeks"));
```

You will get

```
2014-04
2014-01
```

**Edit By Jasper**

Because a date is a moment rather than a week, you request a week and get the first moment of that week. As per the standards, the week number is based on which year the Thursday is in. As such, the week number is 1, but the date is still in 2013.

Comment: Amazing, that's perfect, I thought it was a bug, but you gave the perfect solution, thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure. As Emilio said, dates are always a headache ;)

Comment: Thought I'd go into a little more detail *why* this gives the incorrect date. Feel free to copy any part of my message if you want (and if mine gets redundant, I'll delete it)